# unattended-upgrades on Ubuntu Server 20.04 not working, stuck in shutdown/wait-for-signal

Tags: 20.04, unattended-upgrades

I got myself a VPS a few months back and provisioned it with Ubuntu Server 20.04. I didn't modify any system settings as far as I can remember, certainly nothing that affects unattended-upgrades since I actually want that.

It is my understanding that Ubuntu 20.04 ships with unattended-upgrades enabled by default, so it performs apt update + upgrade on a daily basis to keep the system up to date without the user having to do anything.

I just found out that it has never worked on my VPS in the few months I've had it, so I'm months behind on updates, and I'd like to understand why.

I looked at /var/log/apt/history.log.*, and the only entries there are explicit apt install commands I ran over the past few months. And there's nothing in /var/log/unattended-upgrades/.

A look at `systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service` shows it's been waiting for a TERM signal before starting operation for 5 months.  (see below)

System info:

```
$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ uname -a
Linux vps-713122 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Unattended-upgrades is running, but waiting for something:

```
$ sudo systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
● unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-11-12 20:46:13 GMT; 5 months 4 days ago
       Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)
   Main PID: 867 (unattended-upgr)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1111)
     Memory: 2.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/unattended-upgrades.service
             └─867 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal

Nov 12 20:46:13 vps-713122 systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
```

190 packages out of date:

```
$ apt list --upgradable | wc -l

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

190
```

(Example upgradable package: #linux-generic/focal-updates,focal-security 5.4.0.72.75 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.53.56]
The Ubuntu changelog shows that 5.4.0.53.56 dates from October 2020. There has since been a dozen updates, the most recent being April 12.)

At this point I ran "apt upgrade" manually to update my packages, and rebooted the server. When I checked on unattended-upgrades, it was still stuck:

```
$ sudo systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
● unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-04-18 21:23:29 BST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)
   Main PID: 513 (unattended-upgr)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1110)
     Memory: 10.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/unattended-upgrades.service
             └─513 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal

Apr 18 21:23:29 vps-713122 systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
```

Comment: Does Unattended Upgrades have a PID file at `/var/run/unattended-upgrades.pid` (It shouldn't). If not, then also check /var/log/syslog -- the Unattended Upgrades Shutdown script emits lots of logging.

Comment: No /var/run/unattended-upgrades.pid. 

/var/log/syslog doesn't say anything useful: when I restarted the service, it just logs ```systemd[1]: Stopped Unattended Upgrades Shutdown``` and then ```systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.```

Comment: Do you have a file `/var/log/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log` ?

Comment: Not at the path you gave, but there is /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log. All it contains is the same repeated line ```WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running```, it seems to be from when I run "systemctl restart unattended-upgrades".

Comment: Let's verify that you are not receiving secutiy upgrades: Look in /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log. You should see U-U running each day; regardless of whether or not it installs anything. Remember that U-U only installs security upgrades (which are rare); non-security upgrades queued for later is normal. Look through the past month (or two) and see if security upgrades are indeed being installed. Shortcut: `grep upgraded /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`

Comment: Just checked: Your `systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service` looks exactly like mine...and mine is working properly.

Comment: In /var/log/unattended-upgrades/ I don't have an unattended-upgrades.log, archived or otherwise. There's only unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log, which only contains the same "WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running" log entry as in syslog.   I wasn't aware unattended-upgrades was only for security updates, perhaps what I've observed is normal, but it feels wrong. You would expect a few security updates in all this time.

Comment: Take a look at `systemctl list-timers`. Do you have an active `apt-daily.timer` and an active `apt-daily-upgrade.timer`

Comment: Yes, I have those timers, they're active. The services they trigger (apt-daily.service and apt-daily-upgrade.service) are enabled though inactive. The script pointed by apt-daily-upgrade.service exists, and I can run ```/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install``` manually, though nothing is printed and return code is 0. At this point I'm wondering if we're looking at this the wrong way. Is Ubuntu supposed to auto-update itself, yes or no?

Comment: Ubuntu is supposed to auto-update *deb security patches* and *all snaps*, not everything. Deb bugfix updates that are not security-related are not auto-updated. apt.system.daily is simply `apt update` (refreshing the package database). Those services are correctly inactive -- they are activated by the timers, do their daily job, and then terminate when complete.

Comment: Take a look at the long list of non-updated package that you picked up with `apt upgrade`. Pick a few at random, and run `apt-cache policy <package_name>`. That will tell you which pocket (focal, focal-updates, focal-security) the upgrade came from. Packages from focal or focal-updates should NOT be auto-updated. Packages from focal-security should have been auto-updated (so few should be on your list).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help with this, @user535733. I found the issue, and posted an answer.

Comment: Great detective work!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. According to https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management, "To enable automatic updates, edit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades and set the appropriate apt configuration options".

This file did not exist on my system. Why? I'm not sure. Perhaps my cloud provider has modified the Ubuntu Server 20.04 image they use to provision. Perhaps it was a bug in the previous version of the unattended-upgrades package. Perhaps I got hacked and they deleted it. I'm not motivated enough to look into it.

So the solution is to create that file. Two easy options:

1. Copy it from the default file: `sudo cp /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/20auto-upgrades /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`
2. (WARNING: this will overwrite all existing configuration files for unattended-upgrades) Do a clean reinstall of the package by doing `sudo apt purge unattended-upgrades` followed by `sudo apt install unattended-upgrades`. Confirm that the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades now exists.

I went with #2 to be safe.

Answer (score -1):

Package configuration

```
            ┌────┤ Daemons using outdated libraries ├─────┐
            │                                             │ 
            │                                             │ 
            │ Which services should be restarted?         │ 
            │                                             │ 
            │    [ ] docker.service                       │ 
            │    [ ] lightdm.service                      │ 
            │    [*] packagekit.service                   │ 
            │    [ ] unattended-upgrades.service          │ 
            │    [ ] user@0.service                       │ 
            │                                             │ 
            │                                             │ 
            │          <Ok>              <Cancel>         │ 
            │                                             │ 
            └─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```